# Solidity library openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/utils/Context.sol:15:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, abstract contract Context { ^------^

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity

im trying to follow the tutotial BUILDING ROBUST SMART CONTRACTS WITH OPENZEPPELIN from [www.trufflesuite.com](http://www.trufflesuite.com)

here the link https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/robust-smart-contracts-with-openzeppelin

Creating a "TutorialToken" smart contract

after installing OpenZeppelin and downloading the project template I tried to compile and get this error, I haven't coded anything of my own yet, it's basically an empty project and it should compile according to the tutorial but fails due to an error from the OpenZeppelinon files.

[Compilation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcBaN.png)

Thank you for your time to read this

```
TutorialToken.sol

pragma solidity 0.6.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TutorialToken is ERC20 {
    
        string public name = "TutorialToken";
        string public symbol = "TT";
        uint8 public decimals = 2;
        uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 12000;


        constructor() public {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    } 
}
```

---

```
truffle-config.js

  module.exports = {   // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>   // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!  
 networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }   },
    compilers: {
       solc: {
    version: "0.4.24" //(Default: Truffle's installed    solc)   
    }  
  }
```

};

Comment: Can you paste full contents of your `TutorialToken.sol`?

Comment: sure just done that

Comment: can you please add your 'truffle-config.js' file code?

Comment: 'truffle-config.js' file has been added

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !!!!

its working now !!

I got the answer from OpenZeppelin Community:

> It seems like this tutorial use the compiler version is 0.4.x, but
> now, the newest version is 0.8.x, so I think you should run npm i
> openzeppelin-solidity@2.0.0 to install.
>
> BTW, you can have a look at some newer tutorials:
>
> OpenZeppelin Upgrades: Step by Step Tutorial for Truffle OpenZeppelin
> Upgrades: Step by Step Tutorial for Hardhat